# Is there a way to have Evolution use the system notifications?

Tags: notification, evolution

I don't use Evolution directly but I do connect my calendar to the desktop via my google account. Evolution still seems to use the old-school popup notification when an event is about to happen.

[image]

I like being notified of upcoming meetings but would prefer to have those integrated with everything else instead of popping up in the middle of my session and stealing focus. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?